# Django 404 static files

Tags: django

Django is not serving up my static files

```
PROJECT_ROOT = path.dirname(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static').replace('\\', '/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
```

Error

```
The requested URL /static/css/bootstrap.min.css was not found on this server.
```

Comment: did you call the collectstatic command on server ?

Comment: Have you deployed or are you still on the development server?

Comment: it works on localhost, but I cannot run collectstatic command on Azure server

Comment: And you remembered to set `DEBUG = False` for deployment?

Comment: Hmmm.
You could try using print statements check to see that your value for `STATIC_ROOT` as expected, but I'm guessing it's a different issue. 
Are you letting collectstatic take care of all the staticfiles work for you or are you moving directories around when going from localhost to Azure?
I've found a lot of trouble happens that way.

Comment: Its work when  url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
But very slowly

Answer (score 0):

Django has a really nice principles but IRL it's not obvious for beginners to make it work (and I guess that's why it's not used that much, even though Django is by far one of the best frameworks ever). Here's the idea and [it's better explained here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/):

A web server that do some computations should never ever have to serve static files in a production server. And they are **right**.

Django serves static files, and do this automatically when `DEBUG` is set to `True`.

So you have 2 choices:

- either you set `DEBUG` to `True` on your production server but it's dangerous and not recommended, do this temporarily if you really need it
- or you read the whole documentation and learn how to install and configure what is called a reverse proxy server that either will serve static files or will pass the request to django itself. The classical love couple is `nginx` as a reverse proxy and `gunicorn`. It's like one afternoon to learn this but these are all good principles you should apply.